# How to change the color of table rows once ng-repeat executed

Tags: javascript, python, css, angularjs, django

Hi my Project is working on Django and Python and some AngularJS. What I want to achieve is I've a dynamic history table, which increases when the data populates. I want to add a simple css to this table, like for every even number of rows I need to add a black background to the row and grey for odd number of rows.My table looks like this. How can I achieve that? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                    {%verbatim %}
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><b>Modified By</b></td>
                        <td><b>Modified Date</b></td>
                        <td><b>Field</b></td>
                        <td><b>Old Value</b></td>
                        <td><b>New Value</b></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center" ng-repeat="(k,v) in final_data.histories" onMouseOver="this.style.background='#d2d2d2'; this.style.color='#000000'"
                        onMouseOut="this.style.background='#f5f5f5'; this.style.color='#000000'" ng-cloak>
                        <td>{{ v.username }}</td>
                        <td>{{ v.date_created }}</td>
                        <td>{{ v.field_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ v.old_value }}</td>
                        <td>{{ v.new_value }}</td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`ngClassEven`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven) and `ngClassOdd` directives built into angular, to be used with `ng-repeat`. For example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in final_data.histories" ng-class-even="'my-even-class'" ng-class-odd="'my-odd-class'">
```

Then you simply need to add the `my-even-class` and `my-odd-class` classes to your css, and style as you want.

---

Update: If you have more complex requirements for styling (eg, not just based on whether a row is odd or even, you can apply conditional classes based on any logic you want using `ng-class`. Say you wanted to style every row whose item has a field `myField` that was greater than 5.

```
<div ng-class="{'my-class' : v.myField > 5}"></div>
```

This will only put the `my-class` class on the items that adhere to the condition, and then can be styled as you wish.

Comment: Hi Matt, That was great! and It works also. What if I want to group my objects here based on ID? like other than based on the row number, how can I arrange based on my database ID?

Comment: Means, the user need to check whether the id of the record even or odd, then style/group them based on that?

Comment: If that's what you want to do I would recommend reading up on Angular filters. IMO the best way to do any complex data-driven grouping on the fly would be to throw a data flag on an iterated item and then bind a class to it with ng-class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very fruitful :)